# Can a Player who has forfeited win the game?

Tags: game-design

So take a situation where 4 players are playing. Player 1 is in the lead, but no longer wishes to play. Player 1 forfeits and conceded victory to Player 2. Players 3 and 4 concede victory to Player 1. All players but player 2 have conceded, but the majority of players have conceded defeat to player 1.

Who wins then? Player 1 or Player 2?

This is a general question for board games, but I think something like Catan or Monopoly would be a good reference.

Comment: In general, as several of the answers indicate, a player cannot concede to another player. Monopoly is an exception, though, because of the rules on selling property: a player who wishes to concede can simply sell (give) all of their (mortgaged) property and cash to another player.

Comment: I think Monopoly is a good example.  If you can concede and transfer ownership of your assets then you choose another player.  The question is then, is the person who wins the one with the most assets at the end of the game or is it the last person playing ("the last man standing") even if they have no assets at all?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson That's not a concession, though. Concession means you stop claiming an ability to win. You might give all your property to a 2nd player who still remains behind a 3rd.

Comment: @chepner I don't know what you intend to be the point of contention between my statement and yours. Giving away all of your holdings and money in Monopoly is tantamount to concession. Any difference is a difference without distinction.

Comment: You concede that you lost. You cannot pick a particular player to lose *to*. Even in the political arena, where the concept is most often seen, concession itself means nothing. Concede all you like, if you get more votes, you win. Whether you subsequently decline to accept the position is another matter, and in that case, the position would go to the runner-up, not whoever you choose to concede to.

Comment: Uh, OK. You pick another player to give all your assets *to*.

Answer (score 14):

Why the phrasing "conceded to X"? A person just concedes, states they will not win. They don't get to pick who wins. Whoever has the most points wins. You can't win by giving up when you happen to have the most points.

Imagine on the first few turns I buy a dev card, it's a point, so I concede to a randomly-chosen 2-point player and the game ends but oh, I have 3 points, so the other players all concede to me? I win! Yay? I don't think so.

If the group as a whole all want to stop, because it's late, and are ok with declaring the person with 8 points the winner, then fine, even if the 8-point player was the first to say "I want to quit, so I guess 7-points over here wins instead of me." But if 8-points is not enjoying the game and wants to leave, then the rest of the players can keep playing to see who wins, even though 8-points was winning at the time.

You don't concede to a person. You concede the game. Whether that makes you ineligible to win only matters if your group tracks who wins over time, for bragging rights or whatever. In that case, you may need some rules about how leaving a game or conceding works. (These can be gamed of course, with people dragging games out with "thinking" in order to make other people get tired and quit, which doesn't feel fun to me.)

Comment: The terms and idea of conceding to someone probably comes from 2 player games like Chess where when you concede you concede victory to the only other person involved.

Answer (score 7):

In general, "conceding" is not an action that is specified in the rules of boardgames because it can very rarely be handled in an equitable manner (outside the trivial case of a one-off two player game). One game that does explicitly allow it is Magic: the Gathering, but this can still be somewhat controversial as it can be used abusively.

If this is a problem for you and your group, the best solution is probably to work on your social contract so you don't commonly end up in a situation where this becomes an issue, rather than trying to jam it into the rules of individual games.

Comment: I think this is a good answer.  Only other multiplayer game that comes to mind with specific rules for conceding is Through The Ages.  In that situation you just ‘concede’. I’ve never seen ‘concede to a specific player’

Comment: Agreed about "concede to a player" - but if you can't concede full stop, then the question becomes moot.

Answer (score 4):

"Conceded victory to Player 2" makes no sense. To concede is to admit defeat. You don't get to chose a winner; you simply take yourself out of the running. Seeing that all but player 2 has conceded, they won as the only remaining player.

At least, that would be the case in a formal setting (absent any overriding rule or ruling). But things are different in a casual setting. It's not uncommon for a game to end because players just don't want to keep playing, perhaps because they have deemed a game decided. In such a scenario, who won is purely a personal opinion. So the answer is:

- Player 1 won, as far as Player 3 and Player 4 are concerned.
- Player 2 won, as far as Player 1 is concerned.

Period. There's no objective winner because the game was simply abandoned by its players.

Comment: While it might not make sense in Catan it could in another game where a player that defeats another player gets some or all of their assets.

Comment: @JoeW The OP didn't ask if it makes sense to allow players to concede, and what should happen when they do. That's an entirely different question, and would vary by game. Besides, what you say supports my point that this isn't really about conceding, but about players abandoning a game in a social setting. /// Also, the OP was pretty clear that their question wasn't about Catan or any specific game. ("This is a general question for board games") Catan and Monopoly were merely proposed as models of typical games.

Comment: I think you missed my point, there is a difference in conceding in games where there is no rules about a player dropping out, where a player can lose and everything they own goes away and where they can lose and what they own is given to the player who defeats them.

Comment: @JoeW Yes, but none are relevant here. They would pertain if the question was about whether conceding should be allowed and what should happen when a player concedes, but that's but the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not specific to Catan, but once a player has conceded they are no longer involved in the game, even if the player was otherwise going to win they are free to concede and take a loss in most games, once they have lost, they can't win.